# need to extract a particular field from $response object

Tags: php, jquery, regex, json

```
    <?php
$apiKey = 'HnUvAYIy5hO7iPki';
$apiSecret = '9HBkibOphng7w4p1ZdiiVJgzRI4kpD4Q';

$msg = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"msg",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$message = array(
    'message' => array(
        'message' => ''.$msg.'',
        'chatBotID' => 6,
        'timestamp' => time()
    ),
    'user' => array(
        'firstName' => 'Tugger', 
        'lastName' => 'Sufani',
        'gender' => 'm',
        'externalID' => 'abc-639184572'
    )
);

// construct the data
$host = "http://www.personalityforge.com/api/chat/";
$messageJSON = json_encode($message);
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $messageJSON, $apiSecret);

$url = $host."?apiKey=".$apiKey."&hash=".$hash."&message=".urlencode($messageJSON);

// Make the call using cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// make the call
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo 'Response JSON: '.$response.'<br>';
?>
```

-----------------following is the outcome of above code--------------------------------

Response JSON:

Correct parameters and objects received
raw message: {"message":{"message":"hi","chatBotID":6,"timestamp":1407393907},"user":{"firstName":"Tugger","lastName":"Sufani","gender":"m","externalID":"abc-639184572"}}
apiSecret: 9HBkibOphng7w4p1ZdiiVJgzRI4kpD4Q
Do the following two match?
a702fc336f49b099764d35a548dd110fac2067bcd14a438676e4d579d70b6afc
a702fc336f49b099764d35a548dd110fac2067bcd14a438676e4d579d70b6afc
CORRECT MATCH!
Array
(
    [message] => Array
        (
            [message] => hi
            [chatBotID] => 6
            [timestamp] => 1407393907
        )

```
[user] => Array
    (
        [firstName] => Tugger
        [lastName] => Sufani
        [gender] => m
        [externalID] => abc-639184572
    )
```

)
sent on Thu, 07 Aug 2014 2:45:07 am
6 seconds ago. (limit is 300)
{"success":1,"errorMessage":"","message":{"chatBotName":"Desti","chatBotID":"6","message":***"Yes, Tugger, I've heard that one before."***,"emotion":"normal"}}

**now i need to get the message field content that is in italics**

thanks in advance.... pls help... i tried a lot :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look forward to have a regex solution here it is

**Regex**

```
"message":"(.*?)"
```

**TestString**

> {"success":1,"errorMessage":"","message":{"chatBotName":"Desti","chatBotID":"6","message":"Yes, Tugger, I've heard that one before.","emotion":"normal"}

**Result**

MATCH 1

1. [91-131]    `Yes, Tugger, I've heard that one before.`

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/uF3bU3/1)

**PHP usage**

```
preg_match('/(?<=success).*"message":"(.*?)"/', $response , $matches);
$message = $matches[1];
```

regex updated to match with the full response text

try [demo here](http://ideone.com/dLw6nw)

Comment: need to adjust regex to match with full response, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use json_decode(), it will return

```
(
    [success] => 1
    [errorMessage] => 
    [message] => stdClass Object
        (
            [chatBotName] => Desti
            [chatBotID] => 6
            [message] => Yes, Tugger, I've heard that one before.
            [emotion] => normal
        )
```

Sample :

```
$output = json_decode($input,true);

print_r($output);

echo "<br />".$output['message']['message'];

?>
```